# Accessing other threads or data from POCO HTTPRequestHandler

Tags: c++, multithreading, websocket, poco-libraries

I have an C++ application that reads a variety of sensors and then acts on them as required. Currently the sensors run in their own threads and have get/set methods for their values.

I'm trying to integrate a web socket server using POCO libraries to display the state of the sensors.

How do I go about getting the sensor information into the HTTPRequestHandler?

Should I be using the POCO::Application class and defining the sensors & server as subsystems? Is there another approach that I should be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive from `HTTPRequestHandler` and override `handleRequest()` and give access to the sensor information by for example storing a reference to your sensor info object as a member of the class derived from `HTTPRequestHandler`.

```
class SensorStateRequestHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
    SensorStateRequestHandler(SensorInfo &sensorInfo)
        : sensorInfo_(sensorInfo)
    {}

    virtual void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest &request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse &response) override
    {
        // receive request websocket frame
        sensorInfo_.get_state(); // must be thread safe
        // send response websocket frame with sensor state
    }

private:
    sensorInfo &sensorInfo_;
};
```

Comment: This will work but it won't scale because client must constantly poll for new data and every request for data will take a thread (likely short-lived, though); additionally, depending on new data frequency, many threads may be launched when there is no new data available. See my answer  for a pub/sub type solution.

Answer (score 0):

See how [WebEventService](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io/blob/develop/platform/OSP/WebEvent/include/Poco/OSP/WebEvent/WebEventService.h#L36) in [macchina.io](http://macchina.io/) is implemented - using Poco::Net::HTTPServer, WebSocket and Poco::NotificationQueue.

The design "in a nutshell" is a pub/sub pattern, client subscribes to notifications and receives them through WebSocket; [in-process subscriptions/notifications](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io/blob/develop/platform/OSP/WebEvent/src/WebEventServiceImpl.cpp#L351) (using Poco events) are also supported. There is a single short-living thread ([HTTP handler](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io/blob/develop/platform/OSP/WebEvent/src/WebEventRequestHandler.cpp#L43)) launched at subscription time and the rest of communication is through WebSocket [reactor-like](https://github.com/macchina-io/macchina.io/blob/develop/platform/OSP/WebEvent/src/WebEventServiceImpl.cpp#L318) functionality, so performance and scalability is reasonably good (although there is room for improvement, depending on target platform).

You may consider using macchina.io itself (Apache license) - it is based on POCO/[OSP](http://www.appinf.com/features.html#osp) and targets the type of application you have. WebEvent functionality will be part of [Poco::NetEx](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/NetEx/NetEx) in 1.7.0 release (sheduled for September this year).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had looked at macchina.io but wasn't sure where to start. This is for a relatively simple uni project running on a BeagleBone Black, so macchina.io might be overkill. So far I've found POCO to be reasonably easy to use (for someone who doesn't have a lot of C++ experience)

Comment: No problem. If you want to use WebSockets, see [WebNotifier](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Data/samples/WebNotifier/src/WebNotifier.cpp) example - it demonstrates how to push (no polling) data from SQLite DB to WebSocket client on DB data change.